# How can you build a coinductive memoization table for recursive functions over binary trees?

Tags: dependent-type, coq, agda

The [StreamMemo](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.StreamMemo.html) library for Coq illustrates how to memoize a function `f : nat -> A` over the natural numbers.  In particular when `f (S n) = g (f n)`, the `imemo_make` shares the computation of recursive calls.

Suppose instead of natural numbers, we want to memoize recursive functions over binary trees:

`Inductive binTree : Set :=
| Leaf : binTree
| Branch : binTree -> binTree -> binTree.`

Suppose we have a function `f : binTree -> A` that is structurally recursive, meaning that there is a function `g : A -> A -> A` such that `f (Branch x y) = g (f x) (f y)`.  How do we build a similar memo table for `f` in Coq such that the recursive computations are shared?

In Haskell, it is not too hard to build such a memo table (see [MemoTrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) for example) and tie-the-knot.  Clearly such memo tables are productive.  How can we arrange things to convince a dependently typed language to accept such knot tying is productive?

Although I've specified the problem in Coq, I wouldd be happy with an answer in Agda or any other dependently typed language as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough to get the recursion pattern to work with sized types.
Hopefully the sharing is preserved through compilation![1]

```
module _ where

open import Size
open import Data.Nat

data BT (i : Size) : Set where
  Leaf : BT i
  Branch : ∀ {j : Size< i} → BT j → BT j → BT i

record Memo (A : Set) (i : Size) : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    leaf : A
    branch : ∀ {j : Size< i} → Memo (Memo A j) j

open Memo

trie : ∀ {i} {A} → (BT i → A) → Memo A i
trie f .leaf = f Leaf
trie f .branch = trie (\ l → trie \ r → f (Branch l r))

untrie : ∀ {i A} → Memo A i → BT i → A
untrie m Leaf         = m .leaf
untrie m (Branch l r) = untrie (untrie (m .branch) l) r

memo : ∀ {i A} → (BT i → A) → BT i → A
memo f = untrie (trie f)

memoFix : ∀ {A : Set} → A → (A → A → A) → ∀ {i} → BT i → A
memoFix {A} lf br = go
 where
  go h : ∀ {i} → BT i → A
  go = memo h
  h Leaf = lf
  h (Branch l r) = br (go l) (go r)
```

[1] https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2918

Comment: Thanks for this. I have two worries about this code.

Firstly the `go` value is a function of a Size parameter.  In general, there is no sharing between independent function calls at the same value.  This can probably be fixed by adding a let statement in the definition of `h (Branch l r)`.

Secondly, the stratified definition of `BT` means that two, otherwise identically shaped trees, will have different values when they occur at different levels.  These distinct values won't be shared in the MemoTrie.

Comment: I'm impressed that Agda accepts the nested definition of `Memo` in `branch`.  Coq's positivity checker seems to reject this, making things more complicated in Coq.

Comment: The issue I linked to seems to conclude that the sizes are not a problem at runtime when compiled with the GHC backend, though I haven't verified this myself.

Comment: I see.  I'm looking for a memoization solution that can be used within the proof assistant so it can be used as part of a proof by reflection. Your solution is probably suitable for compilation assuming the `Size` types end up erased.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a "solution" that recursively memoizes structurally recursive functions of binary trees in Coq.  My gist is at https://gist.github.com/roconnor/286d0f21af36c2e97e74338f10a4315b.

It operates similarly to [Saizan's solution](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/40645/4122), by stratifying binary trees based on a size metric, in my case counting the number of internal nodes of binary trees, and producing a lazy stream of containers of all solutions for a particular size.  Sharing happens because of [a let statement](https://gist.github.com/roconnor/286d0f21af36c2e97e74338f10a4315b#file-memoordbintree-v-L271) in the stream generator that holds the initial part of the stream to be used in later parts of the stream.

Examples show that for `vm_compute`, evaluating a perfect binary tree with 8 levels after having evaluated a perfect binary tree with 9 levels is much faster than only evaluating a perfect binary tree with 8 levels.

However, I'm hesitant to accept this answer because the overhead of this particular solution is bad that it performs much worse than my [memoization without structural recursion](https://gist.github.com/roconnor/52375c3a81c927c5a8234be858f9830b) for my examples of practical inputs.  Naturally, I want a solution that performs better under reasonable inputs.

I have some further comments at "[[Coq-Club] How can you build a coinductive memoization table for recursive functions over binary trees?](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2018-05/msg00172.html)".